# Ошибка SQL - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Ребята, уже голова опухла. sql запрос выдает ошибку, я уже выучил его наизусть - ошибки не вижу..

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(e.evaluation), 2) AS evaluation, DISTINCT t.topic_last_post_time, p.topic_id FROM phpbb_posts p, phpbb_topics t LEFT JOIN phpbb_topics_evaluation e ON (e.topic_id = t.topic_id AND e.evaluation >=9) WHERE t.topic_moved_id = 0 AND p.topic_id = t.topic_id AND p.forum_id <> 23 ORDER BY t.topic_last_post_time DESC
```

насколько я могу судить, ругается часть с join ибо чистил его почти полностью - ошибка пропадает только когда убираю join.

ничего конкретного мускул не говорит, просто мол - ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISTINCT не там стоит. Нужно бы так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROUND(AVG(e.evaluation), 2) AS evaluation, t.topic_last_post_time,
```

далее по тексту.
Нет группировки, хотя используется агрегатная функция. 
С особенностями реализации MySQL не знаком.

Comment: точно, спасибо